# memory usage after calling scipy function

Tags: python, numpy, memory, scipy, signal-processing

Consider the memory usage of the following code after executing each statement:

```
import numpy
import scipy.signal
import gc

# memory at this point is ~35mb

a = numpy.ones(10**7)
b = numpy.ones(10**7)

# memory at this point is ~187mb

c = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(a, numpy.flipud(b), mode="full")

# memory usage at this point is 645mb
# given that a,b,c take up about 305mb in total, this is much
# larger than expected

# If we delete a,b,c and garbage collect...

del a,b,c
gc.collect()

# ...the memory usage drops to ~340mb which is a drop of 305mb
# (as expected since that is the size of what we deleted)
# but the remaining memory usage is still 340mb
# which is much larger than the starting value of 35 mb
```

Why is the process using so much extra memory. Is there a leak in the fftconvolve function, or is there some other explanation?

Platform:

- CPython 3.5.1 x64
- Scipy 0.17.0 (Christoph Golke's package)
- Numpy+MKL 1.11.0rc1 (Cristoph Golke's package)
- Windows 8.1 x64